# SSH verbose mode: how to view amount of data transferred without all the "debug1" lines?

Tags: ssh, openssh

In OpenSSH, verbose mode (`ssh -v ...`) shows some useful statistics on exit (e.g. `Transferred: sent 3532, received 3076 bytes, in 5.5 seconds`). However, verbose mode also prints lots of `debug1: ...` lines that I do not care about. For example:

```
$ ssh -v -N -D localhost:12345 user@example.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
--- snip ---
debug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 4
debug1: channel 1: free: port listener, nchannels 3
debug1: channel 2: free: port listener, nchannels 2
debug1: channel 3: free: port listener, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3532, received 3076 bytes, in 5.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 638.4, received 556.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

How do I remove all the `debug1: ...` lines to show the data usage statistics only? I only want to see the `Transferred: ...` and `Bytes per second: ...` lines. I tried `ssh -v ... 2>&1 | sed '/debug1/d'`, but that does not work because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> produces a SIGINT that is sent to all processes in the foreground process group. `sed` is terminated before the usage statistics get sent to its standard input, so the usage statistics are never printed.

I am using `/bin/sh` (not bash) as my shell.

Comment: Read `man expect`.

Comment: @waltinator Could you elaborate? How does `expect` help in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "transferred..." messages are printed at the "verbose" log level. You can set ssh to the "verbose" level using the ["-o LogLevel" option](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#LogLevel):

```
% ssh -o LogLevel=verbose localhost echo hello
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
hello
Transferred: sent 2768, received 2880 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 117942.8, received 122715.1
%
```

You can set this in your `.ssh/config` file if you want it to happen automatically:

```
Host example.com
    LogLevel verbose
```